# Matlab: is it possible to rotate the colorbar of a figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, colorbar

I generated this picture

```
figure(1)
set(gca,'FontSize',14,'FontName','Arial');
h = pcolor(yq,xq, tmpI);
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
axbot = gca;  
colorbar('FontSize',14,'FontName','Arial');
xlabel('\it{\beta_F}', 'FontSize', 15, 'FontName', FontNM);
ylabel('\it{R_0}', 'FontSize', 15,'FontName', FontNM);
colormap(bluewhitered1);
colormap(flipud(colormap))
```

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to rotate the colorbar and having something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the [colorbar documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) there is an [example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html#bt54ya8) doing what you are asking:

```
figure
surf(peaks)
colorbar('Direction','reverse')
```

Benoit_11 comments that on 2013a the command is `colorbar('YDir','reverse')`.

Comment: good catch. Although I think this is for recent versions of MATLAB; on 2013a I need to use `colorbar('YDir','reverse')`

Comment: Using `Direction` it returns `Unknown property 'Direction'` while with your last suggestion does not change anything and I do not why

Comment: @emax That's strange: the above code works for me on MATLAB 2014b. You could put `c = colorbar` and then click `Show all properties` or call `fields(c)` and have a look if there's an obvious option

Comment: I solved it with `h = colorbar;set( h, 'YDir', 'reverse','FontSize',14,'FontName','Arial' );`